# BWDB SQLLite wrapper Release error

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

I am using latest ARC version of Bill Weinman's BWDB in my app at its works just fine in Debug. However in Release it crashes. And only on real device, in simulator it works just fine. I have tried latest BWDB excersise files from Lynda.com and it crashes too.

I have found out that pointer to row is already released, inside forin loop, when you are enumerating the result

```
for (NSDictionary *firstSpecies in [sql getFirstSpeciesName]) 
{
  //firstSpecies is already released here
  m_speciesName = [firstSpecies objectForKey:@"FirstSpeciesName"];
}
```

which make me believe there is some kind of error in implementation of

```
(NSUInteger) countByEnumeratingWithState:(NSFastEnumerationState *)state objects:(id __unsafe_unretained *)stackbuf count:(NSUInteger)len
```

or in enumRows variable.

Do you have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You should post this issue on the BWDB website.

Comment: I did, and i also temporarily fix it

Answer (score 1):

Bill Weinman's BWDB got updated for iOS 7 and this also can solve the problem.

RSSDB.m

A bug in iOS 7 SDK prevents this from working on ARM

```
// for (row in [self getQuery:@"SELECT id FROM feed ORDER BY LOWER(title)"]) {
//     [idList addObject:row[@"id"]];
// }
```

Workaround for iOS 7

```
[self prepareQuery:@"SELECT id FROM feed ORDER BY LOWER(title)"];
while ((row = [self getPreparedRow])) {
    [idList addObject:row[@"id"]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Both __unsafe_unretained and __weak prevent the retention of objects, but in slightly different ways. For __weak, the pointer to an object will convert to nil on the deallocation of the object it points to, which is very safe behavior. As its name implies, __unsafe_unretained will continue pointing to the memory where an object was, even after it was deallocated. This can lead to crashes due to accessing that deallocated object.

In BWDB example there is a row stored to an instance variable *enumRows* in enumerating function

```
- (NSUInteger) countByEnumeratingWithState:(NSFastEnumerationState *)state objects:(id __unsafe_unretained *)stackbuf count:(NSUInteger)len 
{
  if ((*enumRows = [self getPreparedRow]))
  {
     state->itemsPtr = enumRows;
     state->state = 0;   // not used, customarily set to zero
     state->mutationsPtr = state->extra;   // also not used, required by the interface
    return 1;
  } else {
     return 0;
  }
}
```

and *enumRows* is defined as:

```
__unsafe_unretained NSDictionary * enumRows[1];
```

Method GetPreparedRow is declared like this:

```
- (NSDictionary *) getPreparedRow 
{
int retCode = sqlite3_step(m_statement);

if (retCode == SQLITE_DONE) 
{
    sqlite3_finalize(m_statement);
    return nil;
} 
else  if (retCode == SQLITE_ROW) 
{
    int col_count = sqlite3_column_count(m_statement);
    if (col_count >= 1) 
    {
        NSMutableDictionary * dRow = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:1];
        for(int i = 0; i < col_count; i++) 
        {
            NSString * columnName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:sqlite3_column_name(m_statement, i)];
            [dRow setObject:[self columnValue:i] forKey:columnName];
        }
        return dRow;
    }
} 
else 
{
    NSLog(@"rowFromPreparedQuery: could not get row: %s", sqlite3_errmsg(m_database));
    return nil;
}
return nil;
}
```

So basically *NSDictiornay** which is returned from GetPreparedRow method is stored into __unsafe_unretained instance variable *enumRows*. As *GetPreparedRow* is finished, *NSDictionary** is released, because it goes out of scope, but *enumRows* is still pointing to this memory. So rows can be enumerated, but each current row is pointing to invalid memory.

I am not sure why this work in Debug and in Release/Simulator, but it might be that momory is not erased or overwriten right away, so *enumRows* is still pointing to valid memory. I wrote to Bill Weinman and he says it only happens with the newest version of LLVM compiler and only with optimalizations ON. Follow his [facebook page](http://u.bw.org/fb01) if you're interested in hearing when he fix it.

Meanwhile I fixed it in my code by making *enumRows* a __strong ownership, simply defined as:

```
NSDictionary * enumRows;
```

and I changed enumerating function just to set an __unsafe_unretained pointer pointing to this __strong *enumRows* pointer

```
- (NSUInteger) countByEnumeratingWithState:(NSFastEnumerationState *)state objects:(id __unsafe_unretained *)stackbuf count:(NSUInteger)len 
{
  if ((enumRows = [self getPreparedRow]))
  {
    __unsafe_unretained id row = enumRows;
    state->itemsPtr = &row;
    state->state = 0;   // not used, customarily set to zero
    state->mutationsPtr = state->extra;   // also not used, required by the interface
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@DaNY

If I define

```
NSDictionary * enumRows;
```

and then

```
(NSUInteger) countByEnumeratingWithState:(NSFastEnumerationState *)state objects:(id __unsafe_unretained *)stackbuf count:(NSUInteger)len 
{
  if ((enumRows = [self getPreparedRow]))
  {
    __unsafe_unretained id row = enumRows;
    state->itemsPtr = &row;
...
```

I get 1 warning and 1 error (before compiling) :

Incompatible pointer type initializing '__unsafe_unretained' with an expression of type 'NSDictionary * __strong[1]

Implicit conversion of an indirect pointer to an Objective-C pointer is disallowed with ARC